# Upgrading from Win8.1 (OEM) to Win8.1 Enterprise -- possible without clean install?

Tags: windows-8, license, volume-license

I have a Win8.1 Enterprise key. It was acquired via volume licencing.

I have a new PC that came with Win8.1 (OEM).

Is there any way to upgrade to Win8.1 Ent from Win8.1 (OEM) without a clean install?

EDIT: I attempted using "Add Features to Windows 8.1" and get the following error:

> This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key.

Comment: try this tool: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-7-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper and change the Edition of your current Windows to Enterprise, now use a 8.1 Enterprise ISO/DVD to run setup.exe and select UPgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**
No there isn't.  Microsoft does not support an upgrade path between OEM/Retail editions of Windows and Volume License editions.  That's just the way they made it unfortunately.  If you tried to hack it somehow, you'd be fighting their anti-piracy mechanism, whose whole job in life is to prevent pirates from doing exactly that sort of thing.

**Long answer:**
Even though the only difference between Win8.1 Enterprise and Win8.1 Pro is the way they're licensed, the .dlls and associated registry keys that control product activation are different between the two.  The Enterprise version only supports KMS/MAK product keys, but the Pro version only supports OEM/Retail keys.  Additionally, the Enterprise version allows online activation via your own corporate activation servers rather than Microsoft's, but the Pro version does not support that.  On the flip-side, the Enterprise version does not support OEM certificates in the firmware the way the Pro version does.  They also differ in the way they handle hardware changes and the activation grace period.

As you can see, the Enterprise version's licensing service offers certain features but lacks others and vice-versa for the Pro version.  These differences are hard-coded into the activation .dlls themselves and are not based on a config file or reg settings.  And because Microsoft's anti-piracy mechanism is buried so deep within the operating system, you can't just change them out without breaking the OS.

Comment: Mostly right. Pro also supports MAK product keys. I believe they *now* support KMS, but I'd have to double check that part. Good write up though! +1

Comment: Well, I was wrong: KMS and MAK can be used on Windows Pro: KMS can be used to activate computers running any version of Windows that can be a member of a domain. ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831612.aspx))

Comment: I'm not sure if this is accurate, @CanadianLuke.  I don't think KMS activation works on retail/OEM channel versions of Win8.1.  With Windows 7, Microsoft made a volume license edition of Win7 Pro that used KMS/MAK keys, but it was on its own media and regular retail/OEM channel Pro edition keys didn't work on it.  I haven't verified if this is the case with Windows 8.1 Pro though.  But I do know that a retail channel key cannot activate against AD or a KMS server.

Comment: I use a retail DVD, and it activates our mak just fine. I don't use active directory, so I don't know about kms